# How to make discord bot post random gifs/imags

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

hi does anyone know how to shuffle the images/gifs of the bot so that it sends a random gif/image when the command is executed? i know how to do it for one single gif/image but how do i make it so it sends a random one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to create an array within your code to pull the gifs and images out of. From there, we can simply generate a random element out of it using:

```
const images = [
  // images here
]
const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) // Gets a random value from the array's length
const image = images[randomValue] // Gives us the random image.
```